# CSS: Move line up when it breaks

Tags: html, css

In my code below, when the second line breaks, it moves the element below (the ul) down. But I'd like it to move the element above up instead. So that the one below stays where it is, but I can't figure out the right way to solve that.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 190px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="pseudo1">First Line should move up</p>
  <p class="pseudo2">This line shouldn't move the element below it further down when the line breaks</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Stay here</li>
    <li>!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible unless your container is taller than the content, at the moment your text is already at the top of the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help for your scenario. Just add following class.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 190px;
  left: 4px;
}

.pseudo2{
    position: sticky;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="pseudo1">First Line should move up</p>
  <p class="pseudo2">This line shouldn't move the element below it further down when the line breaks</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Stay here</li>
    <li>!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```